# How to define a class whose properties change in runtime?

Tags: c#, json

I have a class called Attributes

```
public class Attributes
{
    public string Length { get; set; }
    public string Size { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
    public string Material { get; set; }
    public string Diameter { get; set; }
}
```

This class is populated from a call to a web service that returns JSON. The web service returns a different set of attributes each time and it is not possible to define all the attributes at compile time as this could run into thousands.

What is the best way to model such a class in c#?

Comment: What are you trying to do with it once you get the data?

Comment: Did you try with a Dictionary?

Comment: Stuff em (or something that encapsulates them) in a Dictionary?

Comment: This question has been answered *load* of times on here, have you even bothered to read into any?

Answer (score 3):

You could use an [`ExpandoObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject(v=vs.110).aspx) for that. In fact, the `ExpandoObject` is just a wrapped [`Dictionary<string, object>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx).

You can directly 'create' properties:

```
dynamic employee = new ExpandoObject();
employee.Name = "John Smith";
```

Or query the underlying dictionary:

```
dynamic employee = new ExpandoObject();
((IDictionary<string, object>)employee).Add("Name", "John Smith");
```

What ever your use is, it is possible with `ExpandoObject`. You can even mix both usages.

Also, this wraps perfectly using JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer(v=vs.110).aspx) to perform the deserialization of JSON data.   Use [DataContractJsonSerializer.UseSimpleDictionaryFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.usesimpledictionaryformat(v=vs.110).aspx) set to true, to have the result be a `Dictionary<string, object>` Type.

Pretty easy to use.